# How to Install Tor browser through command line

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I'm newbie on Linux and I can't install Tor on Ubuntu (Kubuntu) the way you teach. Some applications give a step-by-step commands and it's only copy and past and includes all things to make updates automatically. It's easier for for all.
I made the upgrade from version 17 to 18 of Kubuntu and found out that Tor was available. I install it but does't work.
Can you guys help me, please?
Thank you in advance.
ruiamar

Answer (score 1):

The Tor binary you can install using `apt` isn't the Tor *Browser*. Instead it's just the normal Tor binary.

To install the Tor Browser on Linux see this guide: https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en#linux

The Tor Browser will automatically update itself when a new version is released. For more instructions see: https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/updating.html

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing to install.
The Tor Browser starts with a double click on the "start-tor-browser.desktop" file in the extracted folder.
All you have to do is extract the downloaded file.
You just [download the Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/download/languages/) and extract the "tor-browser-linux64-9.X.X_en-US.tar.xz" file into your "Home" directory.

Open your Command line interface (CLI) and enter this commands:

---EDIT---

Use the absolute path, not the relative path (~/).
It will not work whit the relative path.
Replace "**USER**" with your user account name, like "dude" or "noob" or... what ewer your user name is.

---EDIT---

```
cd /home/USER/
tar xf /home/USER/Downloads/tor-browser-linux64-9.X.X_en-US.tar.xz
```

Now the Tor Browser is extracted into your "home" directory.
Open the "home" folder in a file-browser like Dolphin, go to the directory "~/tor-browser_en-US" and double click on the "start-tor-browser.desktop" icon.

If you want to make a shortcut in to your Start-menu, do the following:

```
sudo cp /home/USER/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser.desktop /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop
sudo chmod 775 /usr/share/applications/start-tor-browser.desktop
```

Now open your start menu and go to "Applications/Internet" and there is your Tor Browser. If not, logout/login.

[image: Tor in Start menu]